# Responsive view on iphone

Tags: html, css

Have some misunderstanding regarding the responsive view on iphone

I coded the @media as follow -> @media only screen 
and (max-width: 375px) { // css code }

On the site jsfiddle.net, When i customize the screen width to 375px is seems ok ->

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width: 375px)

https://jsfiddle.net/Benjamn89/qp5a9o41/30/
```

But when i upload the files into a web hosting the css that coded into the @media are not applied.
As u can see here:

https://bennytal-test1.000webhostapp.com/test1-html.html

Can anyone explain to me why these changes/ nd why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems You are missing viewport meta which is required. add following in to your head tag will help you.

Its working in `jsfiddle` that because they have taken care of meta in background so you don't have to define in your code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: Dear Simut, When i add the code inside the head tag my css styles get corrupted --> https://bennytal-test1.000webhostapp.com/test1-html.html  

    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One|Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

Comment: i checked and saw that there is no css you are missing with css

Comment: ohh boy... God bless u my friend! Many thanks :)

Comment: i am glad that this helped please do accept the answer and do upvote.